# Auth-mode in floggy

Tags: java-me, midp, rms

For auth-mode we may use the following code in RecordStore

```
rs = RecordStore.openRecordStore( "myrs", true,authMode, writable );
```

In [Floggy](http://floggy.sourceforge.net/) how we may use the auth-mode?

Can anyone help me in using auth-mode in Floggy?

If possible please include the example code